# DocuSign automatic anchor tags are not displaying in Conga Composer Templates

Tags: salesforce, docusignapi, docusignconnect

I am in the process of integrating Conga Composer with DocuSign for Salesforce. I have created a new Conga Composer template and have placed the \s1\ DocuSign anchor tag for where I need recipients to sign. After selecting the template in Conga Composer and clicking the 'Download & DocuSign' button, my document successfully gets sent to a new DocuSign envelope, but the document does not have the E signature field for a user to click in order to sign. Is there anything else I need to do when setting up docusign anchor templates for conga composer?[Here are my role settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7wTDy.png)

DocuSign/Conga Button:

```
/apex/APXTConga4__Conga_Composer?SolMgr=1
&serverUrl={!API.Partner_Server_URL_370}
&Id={!WTM_Associate__c.Id}

&QueryId=[NotificationQuery]a1G8000000FkZNo

&SC0=1
&TemplateId=a1O760000008d7WEAQ
&DocuSignVisible=1
&DocuSignR1ID={!WTM_Associate__c.ContactId__c}
&DocuSignR1Type=Signer
&DocuSignR1Role=Signer+1
&SC1=SalesforceFile
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Confirm document has the \s1\ text in it
2. Confirm template was created with the correct role names. Case sensitive!
3. Confirm population scope for anchor tags is set correctly (envelope level)

I suggest you try to use the template without Conga/Salesforce. Directly from DocuSign web app. See if this works. This will eliminate any integration related issues and you can figure out where the problem is.

Comment: I know for sure the document has \s1\ text in it. When I look under Recipient Role Settings I see 'Signer 1', 'Signer 2', 'Signer 3', 'Signer 4' and within my conga/docusign button contains the &DocuSignR1Role=Signer+1 parameter

How do I confirm population for anchor tags? Will definitely try using the template in the web app, thanks for this suggestion

Comment: that's the issue!
Role=Signer+1
but you need Signer 1. 
That's not the same!

Comment: try to not use any special characters in the names of the roles. Like Signer1, Signer2 etc.

Comment: hmmm. I thought the documentation said  Signer+1 indicated a space. I just tried &DocuSignR1Role=Signer1 and Role Name Signer1 and that did not work. Also tried &DocuSignR1Role=Signer 1  and Signer 1 and still nothing.

Comment: Can you try it directly from DocuSign web app? not through Conga/Salesforce

Comment: How do I do that? Just create a new template in docusign app and upload my word document with the /s1/ tag?

Comment: Did not work when importing word document into newly created docusign template

Comment: well, if you can't get it to work directly from DocuSign web app - there's no way it will work from Conga

Comment: you need to create a new template with the documents that have the /sn1/ in the text of the document

Comment: you need to then create an envelope and match the template roles